# Cauchy's functional equation with polynomial: $ f ( u + a v ) = f ( u ) + f ( a v ) + P _ n ( u , v ) $

Tags: functional-equations

> Let $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a continuous function that satisfies
> $$
> f ( u + a v ) = f ( u ) + f ( a v ) + P _ n ( u , v )
> $$
> where $ a $ is a known constant and $ P _ n ( u , v ) $ is a polynomial in $ u $ and $ v $ of degree $ n $. Is $ f $ a polynomial of degree $ n $?

Edit: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use derivatives but rather "clever" substitutions for $ u $ and $ v $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let asume wlog $a=1$, otherwhise take $\tilde u = u$, $\tilde v = av$ 
$$f(\tilde u+\tilde v) = f(\tilde u) + f(\tilde v) + P\left(\tilde u, \frac{\tilde v}{a}\right)$$
and $P\left(\tilde u, \frac{\tilde v}{a}\right)$ is also a polynomial of degree $n$ in $\tilde u,\tilde v$. From the functional equation we have
$$f(x-y) = f(x) + f(-y) + P(x,-y)$$
Lets take $g\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that 
$$\int_{\mathbb R} g(y) dy = 1$$,then
$$f(x-y)g(y) = f(x)g(y) + f(-y)g(y) + g(y)P(x,-y)$$
Also $f$ is continous so $f\in L_{loc}^1(\mathbb R)$ hence $f*g\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and we can integrate the last equation
$$f*g(x) = f(x)+ \int_{\mathbb R}f(-y)g(y)dy + \int_{\mathbb R} g(y)P(x,-y) dy$$
$$f(x)=f*g(x)  - \int_{\mathbb R}f(-y)g(y)dy - \int_{\mathbb R} g(y)P(x,-y) dy$$
the three function in the right hand side are $C^{\infty}$ so $f\in C^{\infty}$
and the proof continues as Aditya sugest for example.

Answer (score 0):

**Rough Outline:**
$$f'(u+av)=f'(u)+P'_{n-1}(u,v)$$
Put $v=-u/a$:
$$f'(u)=f'(0)-P'_{n}(u,-u/a)$$
$$f(u)=P^{\circ}_{n}(u)+c_1u+c_2\quad \text{where }c_1\text{ and }c_2\text{ are constants}$$
<sup>even though $\bf P'_n$ has subscript $\bf n$ it is of degree $\bf n-1$, $\bf P^{\circ}_{n}(u,-u/a)=\int P'n(u)du$ which is of degree $\bf n$</sup>

Comment: A similar approach can be applied to the Cauchy functional equation but is it possible to do this without taking derivatives (like some solutions to the Cauchy functional equation where we substitute ``clever'' choices of $u$ and $v$)?.... I think some of your $v$'s should be replaced by $u$'s.

Comment: Do you mean $P'_n(u,v)$?

Comment: When you put $v=-u/2$ the $P$ term becomes $P'_n(u,-u/2)$. So how do you integrate it back to $P_n(u,v)$?

Comment: Of course, all you are trying to do is to establish that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, so all that is fixable.

Comment: @almagest tried to fix it$\require{cancel}\cancel{?}$

Comment: It is your answer, I think you should fix it! :)

Comment: @almagest I meant "I tried to fix it, does that look good?"

Comment: Looks great, except that it is so tiny! :)

Comment: who said that $f(x)$ is differentiable too?

Comment: @Shivangjindal if we assume f is a polynomial then as p is also a polynomial hence ....

Comment: hence nothing :)

Comment: @Shivangjindal question is "is f a polynomial of degree n" and our our assumption of taking f diffrentiable is just an assumption, which seems to satisfy the conditions for f, note that f may also be non-diffrentiable, but that does not answer "is there a ..." which talks about possibility, if you insist prove it is not!

Comment: Then a  better proof would be.
Assume it to be polynmoial of degree and check the conditions right?

Comment: i)of degree?.....ii)yes checking would be easy

Comment: i don't think this is what question means :)

Comment: @Shivangjindal 31

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17005/discussion-between-shivang-jindal-and-aditya).